# Can't adjust brightness on Dell XPS 13 under Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, drivers, display, dell-xps

Every time my Windows 10 installs a new major update I lose control over screen brightness. I can't adjust it neither via hardware keys (FN+F11, FN+F12) nor via system tray battery icon widget.

Comment: If you're talking feature updates (creators updates) it might be that whatever software you installed to have that functionality is broken. Did you try to reinstall that software?

Comment: @Seth there's no software, it's a native Windows feature driven by hardware keys and power management applet

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In Control Panel, under Device Manager, expand "Monitors" and see if you have a 
 "PnP Monitor (standard)". If that's the case, right-click on that node then select "Update driver". Select "Browse my computer", then "Let me pick from a list". Finally, choose the "Generic PnP Monitor" and click Next to install it. This fixed the problem several times for me.

Comment: I actually may have a customer with this very same issue. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: @LPChip glad if this helps someone else, it's a really annoying issue and I always have troubles finding the solution

Comment: I did it, but it is still not working.

Answer (score 5):

If ccalboni's answer doesn't work for you, try doing the same thing they said, except that you should use the "Display adapters" category rather than the "Monitors" category, like this:

[image: A screenshot of the "Display adapters" tree in the Windows Device manager expanded to show the "Intel(R) Iris(R) Plus Graphics 640" driver that needs to be updated]

EDIT: Note that this only solves the problem temporarily, it may come back randomly. Note entirely sure what causes it to come back yet but this can be performed again and again to solve it.

Comment: Thank you. This worked for me. I tried the accepted answer but that made no difference. This seems to have! :)

Comment: Happy to hear it helped. Although it seems that this only solves the problem temporarily, if someone manages to fix it permanently without having to repeat this answer than please share it with us.